When trying to graph a 2D Fourier transform - cannot evaluate numerically
I am trying to graph the 2D Fourier transform of the function:
(x + I y) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]].
However, I noticed that upon trying to evaluate this function, Mathematica shows no difference between the input and output, including when N is used, or NFourierTransform is used. For example
N[Abs[
  FourierTransform[(x + I y) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]],
   {x, y}, {1, 1}]]]

Evaluates to

Abs[
  FourierTransform[(x + (0. + 1. I) y) BesselJ[1., Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]],
   {x, y}, {1., 1.}]]


And
NFourierTransform[(x + I y) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {1, 1}]

Evaluates to itself. When trying to graph both
DensityPlot[Abs[
    FourierTransform[(x + I y) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {u,v}]],
  {u, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]

DensityPlot[Arg[
    FourierTransform[(x + I y) BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {u,v}]],
  {u, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]

I get a white plot with no information in both cases. Are there ways to make mathematica evaluate this and give me a numerical answer/graph? What am I doing wrong here?

You could try using Fourier as numerical method, but first need to sample the function in 2D. Something like
f[x_,y_]:=(x+I y) BesselJ[1,Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]
len=10;
Plot3D[Abs@f[x,y],{x,-len,len},{y,-len,len}]


data=Table[f[x,y],{x,-len,len},{y,-len,len,.1}];
ListPlot3D[Abs@data]


Looks OK. Now you can use Fourier on the data itself, not on the original analytic function.
fw=Fourier[data,FourierParameters->{1,1}];

This gives the Fourier transform.  Now to display that, there are number of ways. If you search this forum or Mathematica's documenatation on how to display output of Fourier you will see number of examples and different ways. (Need to display the magnitude and phase separately)

Is there a specific reason why mathematica requires me to sample manually instead of simply trying to plot N[FourierTransform]? I can do this the manual way, and probably should given this doesn't work otherwise, but this requires me to choose manually a large enough size length to avoid edge effect, which I assumed N[FourierTransform] would take care of better.

@juaja  But N[FourierTransform] means to find first the symbolic fourier transform. Right? And for complicated 2D function it might not be able to do it since it needs to do symbolic integrals. The N at the start does not mean to sample the function like above.  As for NFourierTransform which is described here I can not answer. I do not know what NFourierTransform internally does and why it did not work for you.  I have not used this myself, and I assume you are using it correctly.  someone might know.

@juaja I looked more at NFourierTransform it looks like this only works for 1D and not 2D.

Using @ybeltukov answer from here:
f[x_, y_] := (x + I y)* BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
R = 100.;
d = 0.1;
x = Join[-Reverse@#, Rest@#] &@Range[0., R, d];
n = Length@x;
m = (n - 1)/2;
k = \[Pi]/(d m) Range[0. - m, m];
X = ConstantArray[x, n];
Y = Transpose@X;
F = f[X, Y];
W = # Transpose@# &@
ConstantArray[BlackmanWindow[x/R/2], n]; 
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {X, Y, F, W};
F // ArrayPlot
F W // ArrayPlot
fF = d^2 RotateRight[#, {m, m}] &@Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}] &@RotateLeft[F W, {m, m}];
res = ListInterpolation[Transpose[fF], {k, k}];
Plot3D[Re@res[kx, ky], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {kx, ky}]


Exact solution for: FourierTransform[(x + I y)* BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], {x, y}, {kx, ky}] is:
$$8 i \text{kx} \pi  G_{2,2}^{1,1}\left(\text{kx}^2+\text{ky}^2|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)-8 \text{ky} \pi  G_{2,2}^{1,1}\left(\text{kx}^2+\text{ky}^2|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
There is a small difference(artifacts) between my solution and  OP @ybeltukov.
exact[kx_, ky_] := 8 I kx \[Pi] MeijerG[{{-(3/2)}, {-(1/2)}}, 
{{0}, {-1}}, kx^2 + ky^2] - 
8 ky \[Pi] MeijerG[{{-(3/2)}, {-(1/2)}}, {{0}, {-1}}, kx^2 + ky^2];

Abs[exact[1, 1]]
(*2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (Gamma[5/4]/Gamma[3/4] + Gamma[7/4]/Gamma[5/4])*)

N[%, 20](* analytical solution *)
(* 8.7914278633666183565 *)

Abs@res[1, 1](* @ybeltukov solution *)
(* 8.96529 *)

Plot3D[Re@exact[kx, ky], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
AxesLabel -> {kx, ky}]


Plot[{Re@res[kx, 1/2], Re@exact[kx, 1/2]}, {kx, -3, 3}, 
ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"@ybeltukov solution", "analytical solution"}]

Plot[{Im@res[kx, 1/2], Im@exact[kx, 1/2]}, {kx, -3, 3}, 
ImageSize -> 500, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"@ybeltukov solution", "analytical solution"}]

Plot[{Abs@res[kx, 1], Abs@exact[kx, 1]}, {kx, -3, 3}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 9}, ImageSize -> 500, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"@ybeltukov solution", "analytical solution"}]


DensityPlot[Abs[exact[kx, ky]], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]


DensityPlot[Arg[exact[kx, ky]], {kx, -5, 5}, {ky, -5, 5}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]

(*Click Shift-Enter and you got a nice Plot*)

